# Can't access full-permission share from cmd as Administrator, can as non-Admin

Tags: windows-7, network-shares, administrator

I have a Windows 7 PC on a domain, with a directory shared as \myPC\myShare. The share has share-permissions for Everyone to have Full Control, and security permissions for Everyone to have Full Control.

I have another Windows 7 PC, not on the domain. I can access \myPC\myShare for read and write through Windows explorer, both normally and when explorer is Run As Administrator. I can access the share via `dir \\myPC\myShare` from a command prompt *not* Run As Administrator; but the same command in a command prompted started with Run As Administrator produces:

```
Logon failure: Unknown username or bad password.
```

Why? What can I do about it?

Comment: The problem is the share's permission is based on the domain, thus your trying to access a share, you don't have permission too.

Comment: So how come I can access it when not administrator? I'm still not on the domain then.

Comment: @Chowlett: Have you checked the permissions on the share? It could be that your account has permissions while the administrator account does not. Be sure to check **both** the share settings as well as the folder settings. The event log might give additional login attempt details, check it on both computers. Also, why exactly do you need to do this as an Administrator?

Comment: @TomWijsman - Yes, the share and the folder are both set to have Everyone having full access. In the end I managed to get Administrator access by putting the client PC onto the domain, and giving a domain account admin rights (even on the domain, the normal Admin didn't work). I'm running a script that needs to be run as admin, and which accesses the shares as part of its operation.

Comment: @Chowlett: Ah right, the local administrator != the domain administrator. Can you post that as an answer so the question is no longer on the unanswered list?

Comment: @TomWijsman - sure, but I'd still like to know why the local admin couldn't access the (full permissions everywhere) directory, but the local, non-domain, non-admin could.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was eventually able to get a local administrator to access the shared directory by putting the second PC onto the domain, and giving a domain account administrator privileges on that machine. That account could then access the share.